# Split Set into multiple Sets Scala

Tags: scala, collections

I have some `Set[String]` and a number `devider: Int`. I need to split the set arbitrary by pieces each of which has size `devider`. Examples:

1.

```
Set: "a", "bc", "ds", "fee", "s"
devider: 2
result: 
    Set1: "a", "bc"
    Set2: "ds", "fee"
    Set3: "s"
```

2.

```
Set: "a", "bc", "ds", "fee", "s", "ff"
devider: 3
result: 
    Set1: "a", "bc", "ds"
    Set2: "fee", "s", "ff"
```

3.

```
Set: "a", "bc", "ds"
devider: 4
result: 
    Set1: "a", "bc", "ds"
```

What is the idiomatic way to do it in `Scala`?

Comment: Are you asking for an "arbitrary" split, or for a truely random split (that would be different if repeated, or that does not depend on the construction of your `Set`).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
Set("a", "bc", "ds", "fee", "s").grouped(2).toSet
```

The problem is that a `Set`, by definition, has no order, so there's no telling which elements will be grouped together.

```
Set( "a", "bc", "ds", "fee", "s").grouped(2).toSet
//res0: Set[Set[String]] = Set(Set(s, bc), Set(a, ds), Set(fee))
```

To get them grouped in a particular fashion you'll need to change the `Set` to one of the ordered collections, order the elements as required, group them, and transition everything back to `Set`s.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible only if it is a List like:

```
val pn=List("a", "bc", "ds", "fee", "s").grouped(2).toSet
println(pn)
```